# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR

Tags: android, console, android-manifest

- When running the code,
  Installation error:INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR Occurred
  Please check logcat output for more details.
  Launch canceled!
- I just try to solve these Error by changing the
  android:installLocation="preferExternal" into
  android:installLocation="auto"
- But still now Error remains the same.So that apk couldn't be installed in Emulator.

**AndroidMainfest.xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.gems.android"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0"
 android:installLocation="auto"
  >
```

**Storage:**

[image]

**LogCat:**

```
E/memtrack(1386): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
 E/android.os.Debug(1386): failed to load memtrack module: -2
 D/AndroidRuntime(1386)  : Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
 W/ActivityManager(381)  : No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/GEMS.apk
 E/Vold(47)              : Error creating imagefile (Read-only file system)
 E/Vold(47)              : ASEC image file creation failed (Read-only file system)
 W/Vold(47)              : Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30
 E/PackageHelper(640)    : Failed to create secure container smdl2tmp1
 E/DefContainer(640)     : Failed to create container smdl2tmp1
 W/ActivityManager(381)  : No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/GEMS.apk
```

- Available Memory in SD Card is also 483 MB.
- If anybody know how to solve these reply me.Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is because of

> ASEC image file creation failed (Read-only file system)

**Mounting, remounting, chmod for SDcard won't help either** - at least it didn't for me

> ```
> C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
> root@generic:/ # mount -o remount rw /storage/sdcard
> mount -o remount rw /storage/sdcard
> root@generic:/ # mount -o remount rw /mnt/sdcard
> mount -o remount rw /mnt/sdcard
> root@generic:/ # chmod -R 777 /mnt/secure/asec
> chmod -R 777 /mnt/secure/asec
> Unable to chmod /mnt/secure/asec: Read-only file system
> ```

Still got  `Unable to chmod /mnt/secure/asec: Read-only file system`

**Adb reset**, as per some accepted answers here on Stack Overflow, was perhaps a part of solution, but it didn't help too. As neither helped deleting **SDCARD/.android_secure/smdl2tmp1.asec** via Windows explorer after mounting **sdcard.img** file(file that is used as an image for SD card on emulator and **can be located in C:\Users\.android\avd\.avd** ) with ImDisk program(please make sure you have on theright tab "Image file access" -> "Virtual disk drive accesses image file directly" radio checked).

What instantly helped was from Android **Settings app on emulator: "Storage"->"Erase SD card"**. If you selected Intel Atom as emulator CPU in AVD settings, you may have to change it to ARM at least temporarily to erase the SD via emulator, since reportedly - SD formatting fails on emulated Intel Atom CPU quite often.

Hope that helps!

Comment: For the emulator, switching to ARM temporarily to erase the SD card worked for me.  This allows me to keep my "preferExternal" setting and get my app installed.  Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Although this works most of the time, even a new emulator and/or sdcard setup sometimes shows this failure right away for me.

One thing that always works for me (and makes for a considerably faster development-test cycle compared to killing images and emus, then rebooting the emu) is to explicitly install the package on the internal device flash - apparently the installation failures only occur in conjunction with the sdcard image - at least for me.

Using the **pm** tool, you can explicitly install either on the sdcard or the flash, so I **adb push** my package to the device's sdcard, then open an adb shell to use pm for explicit installation:

```
adb -e push myapk.apk /mnt/sdcard/temp.apk
adb -e shell
pm install -f /mnt/sdcard/test.apk
```

If you used -s instead of -f you would instruct pm to explicitly install to the sdcard.

BTW - as a related side note:
I also observed that, if the sdcard works in the emulator, using **adb uninstall** followed by **adb install** has a higher chance of success than using reinstall via **adb install -r**. This proved true in several tests, but I haven't invested enough time to say this with 100% confidence. This might also be chance.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting my emulator and recreating one seemed to solve this problem for me.